# Structure Map Profiles and Adding Instances

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

Structure map (2.6).

I have some classes and a registry that look like the following:

```
public interface IManyType {}
public class ManyType1 : IManyType {}
public class ManyType2 : IManyType {}
public class ManyType3 : IManyType {}

public class TestRegistry : Registry
    {
        public TestRegistry()
        {
            For<IManyType>().Add<ManyType1>();
            For<IManyType>().Add<ManyType2>();

            Profile("Profile1").For<IManyType>().Use<ManyType1>();
            Profile("Profile1").For<IManyType>().Use<ManyType2>();
            Profile("Profile1").For<IManyType>().Use<ManyType3>();
        }
    }
```

What I've found is that whether or not I've set the profile on ObjectFactory, SM will return all three instances.
If it's not clear, what I'm after is registering a different set of instances for a given type using profiles.

Am I doing something wrong?

-Joe

Answer (score 0):

That syntax should work, although it is deprecated, here is the current syntax:

```
Profile("Profile1", p => p.For<IManyType>().Use<ManyType1>()
```

Then of course you have to switch to the profile like so:

```
container.SetDefaultsToProfile("Profile1");
```

Comment: CreateProfile(...) is not a part of the 2.6 syntax.